# How to load Avro array of records into Vertica ARRAY

Tags: vertica

My avro files contain the following column:

```
{"name":"my_column","type":["null",{"type":"array","items":{"type":"record","name":"my_column","namespace":"v11","fields":[{"name":"my_column","type":["null","int"],"default":null}]}}],"default":null}
```

I loaded the data into Vertica and stored as `VARBINARY`. Example:

```
db=> select MapToString(my_column) from tab limit 1;
                                                                     MapToString
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {
    "0.__name__": "my_column",
    "0.my_column": "5",
    "1.__name__": "my_column",
    "1.my_column": "9"
}
(1 row)
```

The data can actually be simplified into `ARRAY[INT]`. (I.e. `ARRAY[5,9]`).

What is the correct way of performing this transformation?
Extend Vertica via UDTF or UDParser? Perform this transformation via SQL? Something else?

EDIT: I am going to check whether a scalar UDF can be embedded in the COPY command alongside the AVROPARSER, or wether it requires extra ETL.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try materialising the column - well, you need to know what to expect in a flex table ...

I had this table first:

```
SELECT                                                                                                                                                                     
  __id__
, REGEXP_REPLACE(MAPTOSTRING(__raw__),'\s+',' ') AS rawasstring
FROM a;
-- out  __id__ |                                           rawasstring                                            
-- out --------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- out         | { "0.__name__": "my_column", "0.my_column": "5", "1.__name__": "my_column", "1.my_column": "9" }
-- out (1 row)
```

Then, I just added a materialised column, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE a ADD int_array ARRAY[int,10] 
DEFAULT ARRAY[
  MAPLOOKUP(__raw__, '0.my_column')
, MAPLOOKUP(__raw__, '1.my_column')
, MAPLOOKUP(__raw__, '2.my_column')
, MAPLOOKUP(__raw__, '3.my_column')
, MAPLOOKUP(__raw__, '4.my_column')
, MAPLOOKUP(__raw__, '5.my_column')
, MAPLOOKUP(__raw__, '6.my_column')
, MAPLOOKUP(__raw__, '7.my_column')
, MAPLOOKUP(__raw__, '8.my_column')
, MAPLOOKUP(__raw__, '9.my_column')
]::ARRAY[INT,10];
```

Keys that don't exist in the Map are NULL and not really added to the array. And now I have the array:

```
SELECT                                                                                                                                                                     
  __id__::VARCHAR
, REGEXP_REPLACE(MAPTOSTRING(__raw__),'\s+',' ') AS rawasstring
, int_array
FROM a ;
-- out  __id__ |                                           rawasstring                                            | int_array 
-- out --------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
-- out         | { "0.__name__": "my_column", "0.my_column": "5", "1.__name__": "my_column", "1.my_column": "9" } | [5,9]
-- out (1 row)
```

Comment: But then I need to know the number of elements in the array, which is in fact arbitrary.